# Output clock signal on MKRZERO

Tags: arduino-zero

I have to port a Project written for an Arduino Micro to an MKRZERO.

It communicates via UART with an IC and should also provide a clock signal.

The former code I have used is this:

```
#define OUTPUTPIN 8
#define CLOCKOUTPIN 5
#define CONTRLEDPIN 13

void Setup() {
pinMode(OUTPUTPIN, OUTPUT);
// Needed for initialization
digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, HIGH);
// set clock PIN
pinMode(CLOCKOUTPIN, OUTPUT);
// sets PIN for internal LED
pinMode(CONTRLEDPIN, OUTPUT);

TCCR3A = (1 << COM3A0);
TCCR3B = ((1 << WGM32) | (1 << CS30));
TIMSK3 = 0;
OCR3A = 7;
}
```

As the MKRZERO uses a different IC the registers are not the same. I've waded through the data sheet document but cannot find something similar.

Does somebody have any experience with the MKRZERO and can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The IC on the MKRZERO is an Atmel SAMD21.  Look up the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001882a.pdf) and read the section on timer counter.  Yes, it's a long document, but you will find all of the information there.